# Passing view info to method

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have a simple little app that creates a new wizard character with the click of a button.

I have this in my xml file.  I use the button to create a new view for the wizard profile(via the AddWizardView method) and I use the android:tag element to send the name of the wizard.

But I also need to send along the picture of the wizard that's in the ImageView too...is there a way to get this info when clicking the button and sending it to the AddWizardView method?

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/wizard1_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:src="@drawable/wizard1_one" />

 <TextView android:id="@+id/wizard1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/wizard1_name"
    android:hint="@string/wizard1_name" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAddWizard"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_Add"
    android:tag="@string/wizard1_name"
    android:onClick="AddWizardView" />
```

Comment: Can't you get Image from ImageView's Id?

Comment: It's a bad practice to pass on the bitmap/image to other classes. Try to pass on the image path to the classes and re load it.

Comment: @Hitesh that makes sense...how do you pass the image path?  thanks

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell Is the image provided by you? I think you could try pass the uri if it in the resouce folder (drawable).

Comment: @teckwei it's in my drawable folder of the project and I access it in the ImageView like this: android:src="@drawable/wizard1_one"

Comment: I don't think you can do it with pure XML you need some java code.

Answer (score 1):

you can add multiple tags by define the id for every tag in `strings.xml` like

```
<item type="id" name="wizard1_name"/>
<item type="id" name="wizard1_image"/>
```

and in java you can set tags like

`btnAddWizard.setTag(R.id.wizard1_name,R.string.wizard1_name);
 btnAddWizard.setTag(R.id.wizard1_image,R.drawable.wizard1_one);`

and you can get tags like

```
Object wizardName = btnAddWizard.getTag(R.id.wizard1_name);
Object wizardImage = btnAddWizard.getTag(R.id.wizard1_image);
```

you need to cast object according to your type